# Error in c++ with GSL package

Tags: c++, gcc, gsl

I just installed GSL package to my machine.
I installed in to my director (/u/h)
I wrote the Make file:

```
C = g++
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -O3
LDFLAGS = -L/u/h/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
SOURCES = main.cc params.cc
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cc=.o)
OBJDIR = obj
EXECUTABLE = absimulator

all: clean $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

.cc.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTION) $< -o $@

finish_compile: $(OBJECTS)
        mkdir $(OBJDIR)
        mv *.o $(OBJDIR)

$(EXECUTABLE): finish_compile
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/*.o -o $@

clean:
        rm -Rf $(OBJDIR) $(EXECUTABLE)

clean_run:
        rm results/*
        rm absimulator absimulator_*
        rm time*
```

and I got the error:

```
rm -Rf obj absimulator
g++ -c -Wall -O3  main.cc -o main.o
g++ -c -Wall -O3  params.cc -o params.o
mkdir obj
mv *.o obj
g++ -L/u/h/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm  obj/*.o -o absimulator
obj/main.o: In function `ABSimulator<10u>::ABSimulator(Params&, char const*)':
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC2ER6ParamsPKc[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC5ER6ParamsPKc]+0x127): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_env_setup'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC2ER6ParamsPKc[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC5ER6ParamsPKc]+0x12e): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_default'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC2ER6ParamsPKc[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC5ER6ParamsPKc]+0x133): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_alloc'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC2ER6ParamsPKc[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC5ER6ParamsPKc]+0x142): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_name'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC2ER6ParamsPKc[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC5ER6ParamsPKc]+0x1bf): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_default_seed'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC2ER6ParamsPKc[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC5ER6ParamsPKc]+0x228): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_get'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC2ER6ParamsPKc[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC5ER6ParamsPKc]+0x2c6): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_poisson'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC2ER6ParamsPKc[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EEC5ER6ParamsPKc]+0x2ee): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_poisson'
obj/main.o: In function `ABSimulator<10u>::run(unsigned long long, unsigned long long)':
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy]+0x17f5): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_uniform_int'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy]+0x184d): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_poisson'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy]+0x1ed0): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_binomial'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy]+0x1ef8): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_binomial'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy]+0x1f28): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_poisson'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy]+0x2b0e): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_binomial'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy]+0x2b2e): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_binomial'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy]+0x2b4e): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_binomial'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy]+0x2b6e): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_binomial'
main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy]+0x2b8e): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_binomial'
obj/main.o:main.cc:(.text._ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy[_ZN11ABSimulatorILj10EE3runEyy]+0x2bae): more undefined references to `gsl_ran_binomial' follow
obj/main.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text.startup+0x2bb): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_free'
main.cc:(.text.startup+0x4a0): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [absimulator] Error 1
```

It seems like the makefile can not find the GSL lib, and I don't know why and how to fix it...
Can you help my to find me mistake(s)?
Thanks

Comment: When linking, the order of libraries and object files matter. Put the libraries *after* the object files on the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! unfortunately, It doesn't work. I react you in the first answer.

Comment: The command line for linking need to be `g++  obj/*.o -o absimulator -L/u/h/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`. Notice where the `-l` (lower-case L) option is.

Comment: And please don't post answers when they are really comments or edits to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I did it. Now- I don't get the errors, but the g++ doesn't build the simulation. At the end- I don't get the commend "absimulator".
And I'm sorry about the previous post...